# Hiding All But One Nested Element Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all tables on the page but one based on the following

```
 <div class="col-sm-8" id="contents"> 

    <div id="gridWrapper">  <table id="grid"></table> </div>
     <div id="LogonServer Information">  <table id="grid2"></table> </div>
         </div>

          <div id="info"> </div>
            </div>

  resultId="#LogonServer Information";
  $('#contents').not(resultId).hide();
   $(resultId).show();
```

Where resultId is the id of one of the divs where the table is wrapped in. Im not sure what I am doing wrong? This code just hides everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide all element inside of `contents` except one... right?

First you need to make your id's valid. `LogonServer Information` is not. Whitespaces aren't allowed, so use an underscore `LogonServer_Information`

Then you can use the selector `$('#contents>div')` to select all the `div` that are a direct child of `#contents`. And by using `.not(resultId)` you exclude that div from hiding.

There is no need to use `show()` on that div since it's excluded and won't be hidden at all.

```js
$(function() {
  var resultId = '#LogonServer_Information';
  $('#contents>div').not(resultId).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8" id="contents">

  <div id="gridWrapper">
    gridWrapper
    <table id="grid"></table>
  </div>
  <div id="LogonServer_Information">
    LogonServer_Information
    <table id="grid2"></table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```